# Standalone Tensorflow Projector

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

If you visit the http://projector.tensorflow.org/ you can use it with your own dataset (ie a TSV file). I am playing with N-D data and found useful to look at these visualisations after PCA reduction.

I am wondering how I can run my own Projector version on my machine.
Looking at the doc, it seems to be released only as a tensorboard plugin for seeing the embedding results...

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

According to the replies made on https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7562 more recently than the other answer here, you can get the standalone version at https://github.com/tensorflow/embedding-projector-standalone/ and edit the oss_demo_projector_config.json to point to your datasets.

The demo files are binary files ending in .bytes, which can be generated from a numpy array with .tofile:

```
vectors = numpy.zeros(vector_shape, dtype=numpy.float32)
vectors.tofile('my_tensors.bytes')
```

Answer (score 0):

It has only been released as a TensorBoard plugin.